# Change Password on next Logon for Forms Login with AdMembership providier

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, forms-authentication, change-password

I'm doing asp.net, using FormsAuthentication with the AdMembership proivder.

I'm having to manually write a "change password on next logon" screen because it's not nativley supported in the provider.

I call :

```
if (Membership.Provider.ChangePassword(cpCv.LoginName, cpCv.OldPassword, cpCv.NewPassword))
```

to validate the user and change the password (but not clear the "on next logon flag")

But it always fails, 
(I assume becasue membership validation fails when the "Change Password On Next Logon flag" is set.)

What is the easiest way to validate the user, so I can be sure the "old password" and "username" match before resetting the password and clearing the "on next logon" flag?

I've got the resetpassword and clear flag stuff working, it's the validation that's got me stuck.

Also tried this code, If the Reset flag is false, it logs in, if true it fails to log in.

```
    DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry( path, "jcsn\\"+AdUserName, AdPassword );

    try
    {
        //Bind to the native AdsObject to force authentication.
        object obj = de.NativeObject;

        DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher( de );

        search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + AdUserName + ")";
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add( "cn" );
        SearchResult result = search.FindOne();

        if ( null == result )
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
    catch ( Exception ex )
    {
        throw new Exception( "Error authenticating user. " + ex.Message );
    }
```

Thanks,

Eric-

Comment: I don't really have a solution for your question, however take a look at the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement namespace, it may allow you to reduce your amount of code and might have a fix for you.

Comment: Thanks! I just posted another question becuase I tried using that namespace and got stuck on authenticating. I'm hopign it'll help becuase it makes it easy to clear the flag and then reset it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function called Membership.Validate.  I think your code would look like this:

```
if(Membership.ValidateUser(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text)) 
{   
    //Proceed with the change 
}
```

I'm not sure why your call to ChangePassword is failing though--I think ChangePassword might call ValidateUser anyways.

Comment: if(Membership.ValidateUser(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text))  returns false too.. I think that change password is failing becuase it's calling ValidateUser, which is failing because the AdMembershipProvider does not support changePasswordOnNextLogon and is failing. I think I need a way to authenticate that does not use the provider.

Comment: ChangePAssword Calls validate user, validate user fails when reset is true, it's how AdMembershipProvider is implemented. so this whole approach goes out the window.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old thread, it seems unanswered.

In the [linked forum post](http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/697504-cant-log-user-having-must-change-password-flag-set-forms-au), the developer contacted Microsoft on this same issue with **Membership.ValidateUser()** returning **false** when the Account Option for **'User must change password at next logon'** was **checked** by a SysAdmin:

> The ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider does not allow users having the
>   "User must change password on next logon...." flag set to log in.
>   According to MS this is by design: Because the
>   ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider doesn't provide a mechanism to force
>   the user to give a new password at log on, authentication is blocked.

They went on to give a hint where they used the Security API with FormsAuthentication, but did not provide an example.

Anyone have any ideas?