# Ad Asp.Net Changing Passwords

Tags: asp.net-mvc, active-directory, change-password

We're using ASP.NET MVC and AdMembership provider for login, and for various reasons had to implement our own "Change Password on next Login" functionality.

We also have a nist requirement of not allowing more than one change per 24 hours. so it's set up that way in AD.

What we need is to Ignore that one requirement when resetting a password to default, we want the student to be forced to change the password on the next logon, even if it's before 24 hours.

here is my stab at it. Basically I want to change the PwdLastSet property to a value more than 24 hours old after we reset the password.

```
    if ( bSetToDefault )
    {
        var adDate                  = userToActOn.ADEntry.Properties[ "PwdLastSet" ][ 0 ];
        DateTime passwordLastSet    = DateTime.FromFileTime( ( Int64 ) adDate );
        passwordLastSet             = System.DateTime.Now.AddHours( -25 );
        long filetime               = passwordLastSet.ToFileTimeUtc();
        userToActOn.ADEntry.Properties[ "PwdLastSet" ][ 0 ] = filetime;
    }
```

But I keep getting null back even when I know the users password has been changed.

anyone got any hints or suggestions? Am I looking in the wrong property?

Comment: Recently found that setting pwdLastSet to 0 works better for signalling change password on next login. FYI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm this attribute is replicated so should always be available.
Try the command line script to see if it shows up:

http://www.rlmueller.net/PwdLastChanged.htm

Its possible because its a 64bit date and not doing a conversion? Try the script though and see if it works. if it does, then look at the Integer8Date procedure in it for your date conversion.

Comment: That did output it, and I used the code there to get it, but how do I set it? Thanks.

Comment: You cannot - you can only set to 0 (expires now) or -1 (reset the tie to right now)

Answer (score 1):

If you use System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement then there is an exposed method for the User Principal to expire the password immediately.  So it will be as easy as calling it like such `oUserPrincipal.ExpirePasswordNow();`  for more info about using it please see [this article](http://anyrest.wordpress.com/2010/06/28/active-directory-c/).

Comment: If I do that they can't login at all.

Comment: Are you sure? Because that method will expire the password and when they log in it ill ask them to change.  In MS Documentation it is defined as "Expires the password for this account. This will force the user to change his/her password at the next logon."

Comment: The controls I'm using don't support changeing the password before we login, I dont' remember why, it's been along time since I messed wtih it, but we couldn't get it to work. it's an asp.net logon control that's had it's setting set to unwind it into multiple controls in html. the change password control, didn't, unless you were logged in.

Comment: ROFL, I googled it and got my own stackoverflow posting. it's because the AdMembershipProvider does not natively support it. (Go StackOverflow!) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584951/change-password-on-next-logon-for-forms-login-with-admembership-providier